# send image object created with javascript to controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, form-submit

`<img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBOR…AAjZUMKVM46UAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC">`

the above image is a png image created from svg image using canvas, i want that image to be saved in db.

so im using ajax to send it to controller

```
var can = document.getElementById('canvas1');
var imgpng = new Image();
imgpng.src = can.toDataURL('image/png');
console.log(imgpng);
var postData = {
'imgpng' : imgpng
};
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    url: "../saveimg",
    data: postData,
    success: function(data){
        $('#allpurchasenumberssilk').html(data);
    }
});
```

in controller im using,

```
public function saveimg(){
    $imgpng = $this->input->post('imgpng');
    print_r($imgpng);   
}
```

which prints nothing.

where i went wrong?
is the above method is ok with sending and saving image?

Comment: Did you check firefox/Chrome console what is sent out to the saveimg()?

Comment: @Rahi, Network tab shows Form Data : [object Object]